# SQL Query Where Condition to find something based on date range

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

New to the world of SQL and struggling with something that I'm sure is pretty simple. Is it possible to query a where condition to look for a date in the future based off a date range?

Example. Anything sold between 2022-02-01 - 2022-02-05 for delivery outside of 120 days from sale date.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    (2022-02-01 < date_sold < 2022-02-05) 
        AND 
   DATEADD(DAY,120,date_sold) < delivery_date;
```

You obviously need to put in your table name and column names and there will be variations depending on the database you are using.For example you might have to write

```
2022-02-01 < date_sold 
   AND
date_sold < 2022-02-05
```

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake:

```
WITH data(sold_date, delivery_date, details) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('2022-02-02',  '2022-03-02', 'too soon'),
        ('2022-02-02',  '2022-06-02', 'just right')
)
SELECT d.*
FROM data AS d
WHERE d.sold_date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-05'
    AND d.delivery_date >= DATEADD('day', 120, d.sold_date)
```

gives:

| SOLD_DATE | DELIVERY_DATE | DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-02 | 2022-06-02 | just right |